# Неправильно работает деление в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

вот цикл

```
for(let b = 0; b < short.length; b++){
  if(close < short[b][4]) {
      var del = close / short[b][4];
  } else {
      var del = short[b][4] / close; 
  }

console.log('new')
console.log(close + ' ' + short[b][4])
console.log(del)
```

По моей задумке: есть две переменных, которые могут принимать разные числовые значения. 
Допустим:

```
close = 10
short[1][4] = 11
```

Тогда 10 делится на 11, и получаем значение меньше 1.
Т.е. в любом случае результат должен быть меньше 1.
Но у меня получается совсем иначе:
результаты как больше, так и меньше 1

```
new
9219.18000000 10670.68000000
1.1574435036521686
new
9219.18000000 10700.07000000
1.1606314227512642
new
9081.18000000 8920.00000000
0.9822512052398477
new
9081.18000000 9057.26000000
0.9973659810729443
```

Comment: [mcve] в виде сниппета можно?

Comment: Какие элементы находятся в массиве short?

Comment: я же показал какие элементы находятся. в результате снизу перед пробелом значение close после пробела значения short ,  а ниже результат деления

Comment: я попробовал в сниппете , все нормально делится как и надо, все значения меньше единицы, но в node js так не получается)

Comment: решил проблему задав значениям тип Number, теперь везде все правильно высчитывается

Comment: @Redbeard если вас не затруднит, то дайте сами ответ на свой вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

надо было задать тип данных для значений, которые берутся из json запроса:

```
число = Number(число)
```